# Page zooms out when orientation changes from landscape to portrait mode in iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ipad

when i change orientation from landscape to portrait mode my page zooms out in iPad.I have used vw and vh in styles.This issue is coming only for div which is using vw and vh but not for percentage div.I am usig below meta tag in my header

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
```

And i have tried many solution which are suggested in stackoverflow and other sites nothing is working including buggyfill.js.

This issue i am getting in iPad 2 and i tried in new iPad there it is working fine i.e ipad Air ios 8.

Please help me to fix this issue.Thanks inadvance,

Answer (score -1):

Older versions of Safari don't support the vw and vh units. [See here](http://caniuse.com/#search=vh), But unless the issue is substantially affecting the usability of the site (can't navigate), I wouldn't worry too much about it, since most iOS devices would update to newer versions.

Also I'd remove the "user-scalable=no" and "maximum-scale=1.0" from the meta tag, because you're basically disallowing the ability to pinch and zoom, which is considered bad usability practice.